# ngClass active button function Angular

Tags: html, angular

How can I change the style of each button once I click on it?
[image]

I have several buttons and I need to achieve something similar to an active state, but in reality what you execute is a function.

I tried the following but I do not achieve an active state `[ngClass]=" { 'btn-primary':categoria.nombre }`

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.eventos = this.fs.getEventosAll();
  this.categorias = this.fs.getCategorias();
}

filtrarEventos(categoria) {
 this.eventos = this.fs.filterEventos(categoria);
}
```

component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-sm" *ngFor="let categoria of categorias | async" (click)="filtrarEventos(categoria.nombre)" [ngClass]=" { 'btn-primary':categoria.nombre } ">
 {{ categoria.nombre }}
</button>
```

Comment: Make an array of object in which each object has a state, then use this state to trigger your UI interactions. Also, use English in your code (at least when sharing on SO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first, add a property, let's say, `categoriaActiva` to the component holding the buttons, add

```
this.categoriaActiva = categoria
```

to the `filtrarEventos` callback, and finally add

```
[class.btn-primary]="categoria.nombre === categoriaActiva"
```

to the button.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-w7bgw5) of what you are trying to do

I called one method which sets the value of the clicked index

**Template**

```
   <div *ngFor="let categoria of categorias; let i = index" 
           (click)="changeState(i)" 
           [ngClass]="clickedIndex === i  ? 'primary' : 'secondary'">
       {{categoria.nombre}}
   </div>
```

**Component**

```
 changeState(index) {
    this.clickedIndex = index;
 }
```